# How to characterise functions of bicomplex products

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let me specify real numbers $w_1,w_2,w_3,t_1,t_2,t_3\in \mathbb{R}$, and bicomplex numbers, $w=w_1+i w_2+j w_3,\quad t=t_1+i t_2+j t_3,\quad i^2=j^2=-1,\quad ij=ji$.

I want also to define an operation which extracts the real part of a bicomplex product, $\Re_{bc}(w*t)=w_1 t_1-w_2 t_2-w_3 t_3$.

Then define two functions g and f related as,

$g(w_1)=\int^w f(\Re_{bc}(\xi*t)) \,d\xi$

Finally, let the derivative of the function g with respect to the real variable $w_1$ be the solution of some differential equation,

$\frac{dg}{dw_1}=f(w_1 t_1-w_2 t_2-w_3 t_3)$

The result is a real function, but I want to characterise the solution manifold. Or rather to characterise what I've done with the proper mathematical description. I think of this solution as a bicomplex manifold projected onto the real line, but I feel a bit confused as to what it actually is.

Can someone help me out with the correct specification?